# How to wire two DPDT relays in parallel?

Tags: relay, power-electronics, dpdt

I need two DPDT relays in parallel. They both should switch at the same time. I would connect 2 with 2 and 7 with 7. Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: depends on the control voltage and on the relay solenoid voltage rating ... also, the two relays will not switch at exactly the same time

Comment: Will the two relays be driving the same load?

Comment: You could not guarantee that both relays would close and open the contacts at exactly the same time. Bouncing of the contacts will be different. Therefore the current is not split equally to both relays. The current will destroy one contact first and then the other.

Comment: @Uwe It looks like they're paralleling just the coils, not the contacts. I would guess they're doing that to get the  equivalent of a 4PDT relay, which would probably be a better option depending on cost/availability/physical constraints.

Comment: @Rodo No, different loads

Comment: @GodJihyo Thank you, I should use a 4PDT relay.

Comment: @ipving Okay. I made it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When paralleling the coils that would be the way to wire it. You would need to make sure whatever is driving the coils can handle the combined current.

Since there will be some slight differences in each relay you can't guarantee they'll switch at exactly the same time, slight differences in the coils could make one pull in faster than the other. The contacts themselves could also switch at different times due to bounce.

Since you're not paralleling the contacts and are using them as four separate switches you could use one 4PDT relay. That would at least have the contacts all moving together. Whether this will work for you or not would depend on cost, availability, and physical mounting requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my 2 cents worth ...
Whether you have 2 relays or a 4PDT, there will be mechanical delays and bouncing during contact.
If your timing requirements, for all connections to be at a stable contact state, is within the timing tolerance of the relays (say, approx 20ms), your design should be OK.
I would, however, suggest placing a snubber diode across the relay coils to minimise back EMF when the coils are de-energised.

Answer (score 0):

The contacts will not open and close at exactly the same time. You may do some measurements with a digital scope to see if the time differences are small enough for you. But you need a lot of measurements with different relays of the same type and different age to see the possible range of time differences.

I would try to find a datasheet of a 4PDT relay with specifications about the time differences between the contacts.